# onFling and multitouch - multiple MotionEvent pointers

Tags: java, android

I would like to implement some logic using MotionEvent.getPointerCount() in onFling() of SimpleGestureDetector, however no MotionEvent s are passed into onFling containing any pointer information. On top of this, onFling isn't even called when multiple touch pointers are involved. What do I do? Are there work-arounds? Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the simple [OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) provided by the android system does not support multi-touch events. You'll have to detect it yourself by implementing the [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Comment: I know but I'm trying to detect flings with multitouch events. Not just touch events

Comment: Right, you'll have to keep track between of multiple onTouch even calls to determine when they create what would be describe as a "fling" and then do whatever you're trying to. You could save yourself time by only trying to detect the multitouch fling this way and using the existing onFling even to handle the single touch fling.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to force GestureListener to ignore multi touch pointers and let it consider the first down touch pointer for manipulation of gesture internally.

You just need to instantiate the gesture detector in the following way

```
GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new MyGestureDetector(), null, 
false);
```

instead of

```
GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new MyGestureDetector());
```

Enjoy.. :)

Comment: Although the function mentioned above does work this way, it performs the exact opposite of what the OP asked for...